# Interpretation of variance of negative log probability

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, entropy

Given some discrete random variable $X$ with pmf $P(X)$ the expectation of its negative log probability $H(X) = E_{X}[-\log(P(X))]$ is defined as the entropy which is an important statistical quantity. Are the higher order moments ($E_{X}[(H(X)+\log(P(X))^n)]$) also used somewhere and is there an intuitive interpretation of those?